# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: mdl.Complaint.jobDone, referenced property unknown: mdl.JobDone.jobDone

Tags: java, hibernate

I tried create one-to-one mapping and save SQL db using hibernate,but I run my project I am getting following error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: mdl.Complaint.jobDone, referenced property unknown: mdl.JobDone.jobDone
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at config.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    at config.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at application.JD_Comp.main(JD_Comp.java:22)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: mdl.Complaint.jobDone, referenced property unknown: mdl.JobDone.jobDone
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1396)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1829)
    at config.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 2 more
```

There is my mapped class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Complaint", catalog = "jobcard")
public class Complaint implements Serializable{
    private Integer complaint_id;
    private String nature;
    private String instruction;
    private JobDone jobDone;

    /**
     * @return the complaint_id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "complaint_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getComplaint_id() {
        return complaint_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param complaint_id the complaint_id to set
     */
    public void setComplaint_id(Integer complaint_id) {
        this.complaint_id = complaint_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nature
     */
    public String getNature() {
        return nature;
    }

    /**
     * @param nature the nature to set
     */
    public void setNature(String nature) {
        this.nature = nature;
    }

    /**
     * @return the instruction
     */
    public String getInstruction() {
        return instruction;
    }

    /**
     * @param instruction the instruction to set
     */
    public void setInstruction(String instruction) {
        this.instruction = instruction;
    }

    /**
     * @return the jobDone
     */
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "jobDone", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public JobDone getJobDone() {
        return jobDone;
    }

    /**
     * @param jobDone the jobDone to set
     */
    public void setJobDone(JobDone jobDone) {
        this.jobDone = jobDone;
    }

}
```

other class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JobDone", catalog = "jobcard", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "nature"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "amount") })
public class JobDone implements Serializable{
    private Integer jobDone_id;
    private String nature;
    private Integer amount;
    private Complaint complaint;

    /**
     * @return the jobDone_id
     */
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "Complaint"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "jobDone_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getJobDone_id() {
        return jobDone_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param jobDone_id the jobDone_id to set
     */
    public void setJobDone_id(Integer jobDone_id) {
        this.jobDone_id = jobDone_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nature
     */
    public String getNature() {
        return nature;
    }

    /**
     * @param nature the nature to set
     */
    public void setNature(String nature) {
        this.nature = nature;
    }

    /**
     * @return the amount
     */
    public Integer getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    /**
     * @param amount the amount to set
     */
    public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    /**
     * @return the complaint
     */
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Complaint getComplaint() {
        return complaint;
    }

    /**
     * @param complaint the complaint to set
     */
    public void setComplaint(Complaint complaint) {
        this.complaint = complaint;
    }
}
```

SQL query:

```
CREATE DATABASE jobcard;
USE jobcard;
CREATE TABLE Complaint(
    jobNumber varchar(100),
    complaint_id int(10) primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nature varchar(200),
    instruction varchar(200),
    constraint foreign key(jobNumber) references JobCard(jobNumber) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade  
);

CREATE TABLE JobDone(
    complaint_id int(10),
    jobDone_id int(10) primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nature varchar(200),
    amount int,
    constraint foreign key(complaint_id) references Complaint(complaint_id) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade     
);
```

And I create hibernate.cfg.xml file and I mapped fully qualified class name both classes. why I am getting this error.

**Update**

It's work

Complaint class:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public JobDone getJobDone() {
    return jobDone;
}
```

JobDone class:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "jobDone", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Complaint getComplaint() {
    return complaint;
}
```

Comment: try to post configuration xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, obviously, is that you don't have a property `jobDone` in the `JobDone`. You can use this mapping

```
public class Compilant {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public JobDone getJobDone() {
        return jobDone;
    }

}
```

You will have a foreign key in the `Complaint` to the `JobDone`. And you can delete `Compilant` property from `JobDone`.

If you want to have an association in the `JobDone` to the `Complaint` too (which is not very convenient)

```
public class JobDone {

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   public Complaint getComplaint() {
        return complaint;
    }

}
```

If you want to have a foreign key only in the `JobDone`

```
public class Compilant {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "complaint" cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public JobDone getJobDone() {
        return jobDone;
    }

}

public class JobDone {

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   public Complaint getComplaint() {
        return complaint;
    }

}
```

Comment: @AsankaDJayasinghe Change to what?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using **jobDone** at one place (small j) and **JobDone** at other place (capital J). Correct that and problem should go.

Comment: It is a very strange assumption :)